# JSON Objeto de Objetos

Tags: javascript, html, json

Necessito de criar um objeto json a partir do zero em que cada key tem vários valores/values exemplo:

```
 '{"name":["daniel","dias"],"morada":["joao","allen"]}'
```

Para isso estou a executar este codigo várias vezes, mas o resultado é apresentado com keys geradas numéricas:

facetaPush - nome da key

response - array com os valores pretendidos

valuesFacetas - guardar objecto json final

```
var json_string = "";

json_string +='{\"'+facetaPush+'\":[' ;
for (var i = 0; i < response.length-1; i++) {
    json_string +='\"'+response[i]+'\",';
}
json_string +='\"'+response[response.length-1]+'\"]}';

var json_obj = JSON.parse( json_string );
valuesFacetas[facetaPush].push(json_obj);
alert("valores facetas: "+valuesFacetas[facetaPush][facetaPush]);
```

Comment: editada pergunta

Comment: Qual é a razão de montares o JSON numa string? o que queres dizer com _"a key é dinamica por isso criar o objeto estaticamente"_? podes dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira rápida de resolver isso é utilizando o [`JSON.stringfy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ele aceita como argumento qualquer valor e o *serializa* em JSON.

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```
var obj = {
    name: ["daniel","dias"],
    morada: ["joao","allen"]
}

JSON.stringify(obj)
// Resultado: "{"name":["daniel","dias"],"morada":["joao","allen"]}"
```

Comment: a key é dinamica por isso criar o objeto estaticamente não sei se é possivel

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja algo parecido com isso que você quer:

```
function createMyObject(myKey, myCollection) {
   var myObj = new Object();
       myObj[myKey] = myCollection;
   return myObj;
}
var objName = createMyObject("name", ["daniel","dias"]);
var objMorada = createMyObject("morada", ["joao", "allen"]);

var all = createMyObject("myObjects", [objName, objMorada]);

console.log(objName, objMorada, all)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se este for o seu padrão `Objeto -> Array`  você pode fazer um for para pegar as chaves e outro for para percorrer os valores deste array.

```js
var json = {
  "name": ["daniel", "dias"],
  "morada": ["joao", "allen"]
};

console.log(json);

for (key in json) {
  console.log(key); // Pega chaves [name,morada]
  for (i = 0; i < json[key].length; i++) {
    console.log(json[key][i]); // [pega valores dos arrays dentro de name,morada]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O `JSON` é a representação `String` do Objeto Javascript.
É mais fácil manipulá-lo como objeto.

Você pode acessar uma propriedade do objeto de diversas formas:

```
objeto.chave
```

ou

```
objeto['chave']
```

agora podemos trocar por uma variável

```
var varChave = 'chave';
objeto[varChave]
```

Fiz alguns exemplos para ver se você encontra o melhor caminho no seu caso:

```
// suas variáveis
var facetaPush = 'name';
var response = ['daniel', 'dias'];

var objeto = {};
objeto[facetaPush] = response; // exemplo com variáveis
objeto['morada'] = ['joao', 'allen']; // exemplo estático
objeto.morada = ['joao', 'allen']; // exemplo estático
```

Veja como o JSON ficaria:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(objeto);
// Resultado: "{"name":["daniel","dias"],"morada":["joao","allen"]}"
```